# Is this a 3/4 in. regulator, or a 1-in. regulator?

Tags: plumbing, pex

The image shows my home water pressure regulator and the 3/4 in. PEX coming out the low pressure side. I think (hope) it might be a 1-in regulator using a threaded adapter reducing to 3/4 in. Both sides look the same and use 3/4 pipe. The home was built in 2016.

[image]

(United States plumbing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a [3/4" PEX Barb Union for PRV](https://www.plumbersstock.com/vwprv34-union-only-34in-pex-barb-union-for-prv-per-each.html?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&scid=scplp91118&sc_intid=91118&gclid=CMGCwNGhns8CFckfhgodalIMNQ). So it doesn't appear to be a reducer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any indication that the pressure reducing valve is a different size than the pipe. What part do you think is the threaded adapter? If the pipe is 3/4 and the home was built this year I don't see why they would've used a 1" PRV with adapters.

Can you find a part number on the PRV anywhere?

Comment: Well the water main coming into the house is 1 inch. Reduces before the PRV.

Comment: Well, to a non-plumber like myself, the PEX fitting *does* reduce the size of the actual space in which the water can flow (see image by following the link in the accepted answer). As someone more knowledgeable explained to me, PEX is measured by outside diameter. Metal pipes are measured by inside diameter. (Even if this isn't strictly true, the point is that the *actual* space in which the water flows is smaller in 1-inch PEX than in 1-inch copper pipe). One can easily see that in the original image posted in the question, the fitting is indeed restricting the flow of water.